# pandas combine nested dataframes into one single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nested

I have a dataframe, where in one column (we'll call it `info`) all the cells/rows contain another dataframe inside. I want to loop through all the rows in this column and literally stack the nested dataframes on top of each other, because they all have the same columns

How would I go about this?

Comment: Please add a toy example and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

length=5

# some dfs
nested_dfs = [pd.DataFrame({'a': [*range(length)],
                            'b': [*range(length)]}) for x in range(length)]

print(nested_dfs[0])

   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4

# df with nested_dfs in info
df = pd.DataFrame({'info_col': nested_dfs})

# code to be implemented
lst_dfs = df['info_col'].values.tolist()
df_final = pd.concat(lst_dfs,axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df_final.tail()

    a  b
20  0  0
21  1  1
22  2  2
23  3  3
24  4  4
```

This method should be a bit faster than the solution offered by [nandoquintana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73089307/18470692), which also works.

---

Incidentally, it is ill advised to name a df column `info`. This is because [`df.info`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) is actually a function. E.g., normally `df['col_name'].values.tolist()` can also be written as `df.col_name.values.tolist()`. However, if you try this with `df.info.values.tolist()`, you will run into an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'values'
```

You also run the risk of overwriting the function if you start assigning values to your column on top of doing something which you probably don't want to do. E.g.:

```
print(type(df.info))
<class 'method'>

df.info=1

# column is unaffected, you just create an int variable
print(type(df.info))
<class 'int'>

# but:
df['info']=1

# your column now has all 1's
print(type(df['info']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Amazing! Love just passing the list to `concat`, which eliminates the need for a for-loop. The "info" column was just for the example here on SO, but a good reminder nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I figured it probably would be. Better safe than sorry, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with, although it's not the fastest which is why I am still leaving the question unanswered

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for frame in df['Info'].tolist():
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, frame], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Our dataframe has three columns (`col1`, `col2` and `info`).

In `info`, each row has a nested df as value.

```
import pandas as pd

nested_d1 = {'coln1': [11, 12], 'coln2': [13, 14]}
nested_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=nested_d1)
nested_d2 = {'coln1': [15, 16], 'coln2': [17, 18]}
nested_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=nested_d2)

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'info': [nested_df1, nested_df2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

We could combine all nested dfs rows appending them to a list (as nested dfs schema is constant) and concatenating them later.

```
nested_dfs = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    nested_dfs.append(row['info'])

result = pd.concat(nested_dfs, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True) 

print(result)
```

This would be the result:

```
   coln1  coln2
0     11     13
1     12     14
2     15     17
3     16     18
```